# Host Php script from codecanyon on wordpress

Tags: installation

I have purchased a script from codecanyon.It is PHP version 8.1 supported. Can I host it on WordPress? At this time hosted it through cpanel.

Comment: What does it do? Is it just a single PHP, or are there more files too? Do you just want to run it on the same server or integrate with WordPress (site layout, logged in users, etc.) in any way? Does it have database etc. requirements as well?

Comment: You probably can just put it on the same server, perhaps with a bit of care around where you put it or htaccess or similar configuration. If you want to do anything more complex you might need to do some work.

Comment: When you say "hosted through cpanel" you mean you've just uploaded the files to a web server somewhere that you run through cpanel?

Comment: It's probably also worth asking the authors of the script if they have a WordPress-integrated version already.